# 2048-bit RSA public key being misread as 1024-bit in IOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, encryption, openssl, rsa

I've generated an RSA keypair using the following commands on my Linux box:

```
openssl genrsa -out private.pem 2048
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -in private.pem -outform DER -out private.der -nocrypt
openssl req -new -x509 -keyform PEM -key private.pem -outform DER -out public.der
```

Running the following confirms "Public-key: (2048 bit)":

```
openssl x509 -in public.der -inform DER -text -noout
```

In my IOS app, I read the bytes of public.der file from the network, and I extract the public key like so:

```
NSData *certificateData = [RequestManager getDataFromUrl:@"http://dyner.me/crypto.der"];
if (certificateData) {
    SecCertificateRef certificateFromFile = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, (__bridge CFDataRef)certificateData);
    SecPolicyRef secPolicy = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509();
    SecTrustRef trust;
    OSStatus statusTrust = SecTrustCreateWithCertificates(certificateFromFile, secPolicy, &trust);
    SecTrustResultType resultType;
    OSStatus statusTrustEval =  SecTrustEvaluate(trust, &resultType);
    SecKeyRef publicKey = SecTrustCopyPublicKey(trust);
}
```

The resulting SecKeyRef, however, shows a block size of 1024 bits:

```
<SecKeyRef algorithm id: 1, key type: RSAPublicKey, version: 3, block size: 1024 bits, exponent: {hex: 10001, decimal: 65537}, modulus: B9059150BD2933FEC3E2DAC6036E5FE7FC61CEE8B7081AD6BCCE2FA0F340232CFE3DD0B025E6DCFD3755F732ED8292F687DE421AD46FAFA5672ACC2D1C875D4644ED7ACF07E8EA3CAEDF245A27BF61ED1E0AD57D2B4F92AE1222C51A8A980E5D2C7308592E179B4EEE811C6A97358B9F87A9BEB7A08B6893CC1CBBA231B38E85, addr: 0x7f86ca831600>
```

Why is this block size not "2048 bits"?

Comment: That doesn't look like the same key.  The modulus is completely different.  Did you recently replace an older key on the server?

Comment: Yes, I tried a couple of times to make the cert in different ways.  They all end up saying "2048-bit" and are not able to be read as such with the IOS code above.  They *are* read, suspiciously, and that SecKeyRef seems to contain a valid 1024-bit public key.  I've used it to encrypt a small amount of data (< 128 bytes) that was successfully decrypted on the server using it's private key.

Comment: Any ideas?  I still haven't got this sorted.

Comment: What I am saying is, is it possible that the previously downloaded key is cached on the device so that you are seeing the same key over and over again without actually fetching it from the server?